# Dynamically load SVG groups when visible

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have a (pretty large) SVG file which I embed in an HTML page inside a fixed-width `<div>` (using the `<object>` tag such that clicking elements can start SVG animations).

The SVG is much wider than the div such that, at a time, only a small part of it is visible. A horizontal scroll function can be used select the visible part.

Nevertheless, the browser seems to load the entire SVG at once which makes it terribly slow. The SVG contains many groups which contain most of the structure. Supposedly, ignoring the content of invisible groups would make it much faster.

What are my options to dynamically load SVG groups only when they become, or are about to become, visible? And then to unload them when they leave the `<div>` again?

Currently the SVG is *not* inline and I am using only SVG animations for the content of the graphic and javascript animations for the horizontal scrolling.

Comment: browsers do have to load the whole SVG as without doing that there's no a-priori way to determine what is or is not visible. They only render what you see though.

Comment: Ok, but that's terminology. I can rephrase the question as "What options do I have to tell the browser to parse the substructure of groups only when these become visible?" Btw: Not only is the initial loading of this file very slow, also the scrolling of the loaded file is not fast enough. I don't know if the problem is the rendering there, or the determination of what needs to be rendered.

Comment: As I said, nothing at all, they already work like that.

Comment: For example: I can use javascript to add an SVG-group to a SVG-document, right? So I could start with a smaller document and add groups only if visible. I can determine this, in principle, using the javascript that does the scrolling, knowing the location of the groups. Shouldn't this work, with an inline SVG at least? I don't know if this efficient though because I am not sure if the browser parse the entire SVG again.

Comment: Browsers only parse what you add.

Comment: That's a good new. I have an independent way to determine the approximate location of the groups' content which lies in the process of their creation, if that's difficult to find out otherwise.